# Remove active users of hotspot

Tags: mikrotik, hotspot

I want to remove active hotspot users with below code but says :

> **no such item**

```
mikrotik.Send("/ip/hotspot/active/remove");
mikrotik.Send("=.id=" + username,true);
```

below is screenshot of mikrotik hotspot
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is finding the correct **.id** of the active hotspot user by doing ...

```
/ip/hotspot/active/print
```

You will receive a List of Active Users like this:

```
[tag=3, data={idle-time=6s, uptime=47s, bytes-out=121490,.id=*AC100016, mac-address=2C:AE:2B:9A:22:37, packets-out=314, session-time-left=59m13s, login-by=http-chap, bytes-in=47381, address=172.16.0.22, radius=false, server=SERVER_TEST, user=0872test, packets-in=330}]
```

In this case, the .id you need is **.id=*AC100016**

Now, I give you and example of my method **deleteActiveUser()** . It has benn done in Java but in my opinion it's clear:

```
public boolean deleteActiveUser(String id_param){
        boolean ret = true;
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("/ip/hotspot/active/remove .id=");
            sb.append(id_param);

            this.getConnection(this.mikrotik).execute(sb.toString());

            } catch (MikrotikApiException e) {
                ret = false;
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ret = false;

        } finally {

            closeConnection();
        }

        return ret;

    }
```